# Show CiviCRM events in fullcalendar

Tags: calendar

We currently show our events, from "Google Calendar", in our Wordpress website calendar, using Fullcalendar (fullcalendar.io).
But we would like to show instead our CiviCRM events in this calendar (and not using 'Google Calendar' any longer). How to do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to CiviCRM SE. Have you tried [CiviCRM Event Calendar](https://github.com/osseed/com.osseed.eventcalendar) or [CiviCalendar](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicalendar).

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way not using an extension?

Comment: You will need to use civi api to fetch the event and pass it to calendar plugin

Comment: Could you detail how to proceed? Thanks.

Comment: How about https://github.com/agileware/wp-civicrm-ux/blob/master/USAGE.md#event-listing-shortcode ?